# Background image is slided upwards when keyboard is opend

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am facing issue in building a login page in android. I want to keep the username and login at bottom of my layout. But when entering username/password keyboard pops up, and also my background image slides along with it. I want that my background image should be static and only my login layout should slide upwards when keyboard pops up. I have added fragment with my login layout inside the activity and have added background image in activity layout.

Here is my fragments and activity layout code:

fragment_login.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/username_login_form" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:orientation="vertical">

      <com.test.views.CustomEditText android:id="@+id/usernameview" android:layout_width="@dimen/login_edittext_width" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_margin="12dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:hint="@string/prompt_username" android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:inputType="text|textPersonName|textFilter|textNoSuggestions" android:maxLines="1" android:padding="16dp" android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:scrollHorizontally="true"
      android:singleLine="true" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" android:textSize="16sp" />


      <com.test.views.CustomEditText android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="@dimen/login_edittext_width" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_margin="8dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:hint="@string/prompt_password" android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:inputType="textPassword" android:maxLines="1" android:padding="16dp" android:singleLine="true" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
      android:textSize="16sp" />


      <Button android:id="@+id/sign_in_button" android:layout_width="@dimen/login_button_width" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_margin="8dp" android:background="@drawable/blue_btn_selector" android:imeOptions="actionDone"
      android:paddingLeft="26dp" android:paddingRight="26dp" android:text="@string/sign_in" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:textSize="@dimen/signin_button_textsize" android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView android:id="@+id/forgot_password" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="@string/forgot_password" android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:textSize="14sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@id/username_login_form" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" android:text="text" android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="42sp" />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <!-- Login progress -->
  <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLargeInverse" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:visibility="gone"
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@mipmap/login_background" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="com.test.activity.LoginActivity">

  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_layout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: issue image] 
[Background image sliding upwards when keyboard pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeNCM.png)

[image: issue image] 
[Background image should be static always and it should not slide upwards when keyboard pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1k5o.jpg)

Comment: I don't see background image sliding up! Only EditText is sliding upward and this is expected behavior!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the background to your window not not your layout so that is is not dependent to layout changes. Example;

```
        getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(yourBackgroundid);
```

In some devices above code won't sork so you have to do it like this.

```
        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
        getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(yourBackgroundid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code in your Java Code:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagename));
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml add Following code in your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```